# Let $X,Y,Z$ be three random variables such that the correlation coefficients $\rho_{XY}=0.2, \rho_{YZ}=0.2$, what values can $\rho_{XZ}$ take?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, normal-distribution, correlation, cholesky-decomposition

Let $(X,Y,Z)^T$ be jointly normal variable with zero mean such that the correlation coefficients $\rho_{XY}=0.2, \rho_{YZ}=0.2$, what values can $\rho_{XZ}$ take?

Prove that there exists a decomposition

$Y=aN_2,$

$X=bN_1+cN_2,$

$Z=dN_1+eN_2+fN_3,$

where $N_1,N_2,N_3$ are independent stand normal variables.

I know that the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ is a semi positive definite matrix and hence admits a Cholesky decomposition $\Sigma = LL^T$. But I am not sure how to proceed

Comment: The algorithm for the Cholesky decomposition is quite simple. When you write it out you will find the necessary and sufficient condition for $\rho_{XZ}$.

Comment: Are the individual variances known?

Comment: Assume wlog that the variances are equal to 1 and use the Sylvester criterion: the third leading principal minor should be non-negative. This will give the answer $[-1, 23/25]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the covariance matrix of $(X,Y,Z)^T$, $C=\mathbb E[[X,Y,Z]^T[X,Y,Z]]$. (since the means are $0$)

Compute the individual variance and standard deviation of $X,Y,Z$, call it $\sigma_X,\sigma_Y,\sigma_Z$.

Define the covariance of normalized variables $\frac{X}{\sigma_X},\frac{Z}{\sigma_Z},\frac{Z}{\sigma_Z}$, we call it $\bar C$.

For this normalized covariance matrix, it shall has this structure
$$\bar C=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.2 & \rho\\
0.2 & 1 & 0.2\\
\rho & 0.2 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Note scale and shifting of random variables do not change the pearson correlation among them. so here $\rho=\rho_{XZ}$

To make $\bar C$ a valid covariance matrix, it needs to be positive (semi-)definite. Using a generalized version of Sylvester criterion for pos-semi-definite matrices, we need to show all principal minors are non-negative (in contrast to leading ones are positive).

This criterion comes down to
$$
\det(\bar C)\geq 0\\
\det(\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho\\
\rho & 1\\
\end{bmatrix})\geq0
$$
Which translates to
$$
1-\rho^2\geq 0\\
\frac{576}{25^2}-(\rho-\frac 1{25})^2\geq 0
$$

Then you get the range of the correlation between $X,Z$. $[-\frac{23}{25},1]$
$$
-\frac{23}{25}\leq \rho\leq 1
$$

For the last part, notice how linear transform affects the covariance of normal variables. Generally, for multivariate Gaussian
$U\sim \mathcal N(0,C)$ the transform it with an invertible transform $V=AU$, $V\sim \mathcal N(0,ACA^T)$.

Thus if you have three independent standard normal variable $[N_1,N_2,N_3]^T\sim \mathcal N(0,I)$. Then if we have a Cholesky decomposition of $C=LL^T$ we can define the random variables $L[N_1,N_2,N_3]^T\sim \mathcal N(0,LL^T)=\mathcal N(0,C)$

Thus we find the transform that maps independent normal variables to $X,Y,Z$

$$
[X,Y,Z]^T=L[N_1,N_2,N_3]^T
$$

*Prussing, John E.*, [**The principal minor test for semidefinite matrices**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2514/3.20077), J. Guid. Control Dyn. 9, 121-122 (1986). [ZBL0599.15010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0599.15010).

Comment: Super interesting! I am a bit puzzled, though. This seems to imply that a perfect negative correlation, -1, is not possible. Can you please explain whether I am correct or what I am missing?

Comment: I also came to this conclusion! I think intuitively since XY, YZ are positive correlation then X-Z cannot be too negatively correlated.

Comment: Geometrically my understanding is that, $X$ (realized as a data vector) and $Y$ has an acute angle less than $\pi/2$, similarly $Y,Z$ has an acute angle less than $\pi/2$. Then $X,Z$ cannot be opposite direction to each other, there is a largest angle you can have between them -- corresponding to the minimum correlation

Comment: Seems that I got wrong signs in my comment... Good job!

Comment: @zhoraster your answer definitely inspired me! :) Also i used a generalized sylvester criterion (which requires non negativity of all minorvinstead of the leading ones

Comment: Actually, in this case it is possible to verify semidefiniteness "using only the leading minors". The trick is that inside the interval $(-23/25,1)$, the matrix is **positive definite** (which is verified by testing only the leading minors), so thanks to continuity, it is positive semidefinite for $\rho = -23/25$ and $\rho = 1$.

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 I keep coming back to this answer because it is so interesting. I have a question though. In "Define the covariance of normalized variables $X/\sigma_{X}, Z/\sigma_{Z}, Z/\sigma_{Z}$  we call it $\bar{C}$", did you mean $Y/\sigma_{Y}$ instead of the second $Z/\sigma_{Z}$?