# Bounding Correlation

Tags: correlation

I need to find min/max possible values of $q$ in the following situation.

"Consider random variables $x, y$, and $z$. Suppose it is known that $\operatorname{Corr}[x, y]=\operatorname{Corr}[x, z]=$ $0.5$. Denote $q=\operatorname{Corr}[y, z]$."

I can easily see that max is $1$ if Y = Z. However, can't find how to approach this problem to find minimum. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ll shamelessly refer to my answer to a super similar question with only different numbers.

[Let $X,Y,Z$ be three random variables such that the correlation coefficients $\rho_{XY}=0.2, \rho_{YZ}=0.2$, what values can $\rho_{XZ}$ take?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443480/let-x-y-z-be-three-random-variables-such-that-the-correlation-coefficients-r/4450034#4450034)

You re right about the upper bound which is $1$.
The constraint on lower bound is the covatiance matrix of the 3 variables shall be (semi) positive definite.

Then we could apply Sylvester theorem to derive the criterion for the covariance to be positive definite.

---

More specifically, normalizing variables won't change their correlation or positive definiteness of the covariance, so we consider the normalized variables $x',y'z'$.
$$Cov([x',y',z'])=
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0.5&0.5\\
0.5&1&q\\
0.5&q&1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
By Generalized Sylvester Theorem we need to ensure all principal minor to be non-negative definite.
$$
1-q^2\geq 0 \\
\det Cov=1-q^2+\frac  12(q-1)\geq 0
$$
You get $-0.5\leq q\leq 1$