# Inequality with correlation coefficient

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, solution-verification

Let $X,Y,Z$ be random variables with median $0$ and variance $1$. Define $\rho_{1}:=\rho(X,Y)$, $\rho_{2}:=\rho(Y,Z)$ and $\rho_{3}:=\rho(X,Z)$. Show

$$\rho_{1}\rho_{2}-\sqrt{1-\rho_{1}^{2}}\sqrt{1-\rho_{2}^{2}}\leqslant\rho_{3}.$$

From the properties of $\rho$, $\rho_{i}^{2}\leq1$, $i=1,2,3$. That implies $-\sqrt{1-\rho_{1}^{2}}\sqrt{1-\rho_{2}^{2}}\leq0$.

Also, $|\rho_{1}||\rho_{2}|\leq1\wedge|\rho_{3}|\leq1\implies|\rho_{1}||\rho_{2}|-|\rho_{3}|\leq0$.

With both inequalties,

$$|\rho_{1}||\rho_{2}|-\sqrt{1-\rho_{1}^{2}}\sqrt{1-\rho_{2}^{2}}\leq|\rho_{3}|.$$

Is this correct? If so, how do I get rid of the absolute values?

Comment: $|\rho_{1}||\rho_{2}|\leq1\wedge|\rho_{3}|\leq1\implies|\rho_{1}||\rho_{2}|-|\rho_{3}|\leq0$ looks strange both as an implication and as a statement about correlations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The covariance matrix of $X,Y,Z$ has to be positive semi-definite, since unit variance, it's just the correlation matrix.
$$
Cov(X,Y,Z)=C=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho_1 &\rho_3 \\
\rho_1 & 1 &\rho_2 \\
\rho_3 & \rho_2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which means all the principal minors ($\det$ of submatrices) have to be non-negative.
$$
\det C=1+2\rho_1\rho_2\rho_3 -\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2-\rho_3^2\geq 0 \\
1-\rho_i^2\geq 0,i=1,2,3
$$
We can re-arrange the first condition to make it closer to your target.
$$
-2\rho_1\rho_2\rho_3+\rho_3^2\leq 1-\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2\\
\rho_1^2\rho_2^2-2\rho_1\rho_2\rho_3+\rho_3^2\leq 1-\rho_1^2-\rho_2^2+\rho_1^2\rho_2^2\\
(\rho_1\rho_2-\rho_3)^2\leq (1-\rho_{1}^{2})(1-\rho_{2}^{2})\\
$$
Since the second condition, $1-\rho_i^2\geq 0$ we can take it under sqrt. Thus
$$
-\sqrt{(1-\rho_{1}^{2})(1-\rho_{2}^{2})}\leq\rho_1\rho_2-\rho_3\leq \sqrt{(1-\rho_{1}^{2})(1-\rho_{2}^{2})}
$$

Related answer
[Let $X,Y,Z$ be three random variables such that the correlation coefficients $\rho_{XY}=0.2, \rho_{YZ}=0.2$, what values can $\rho_{XZ}$ take?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4443480/let-x-y-z-be-three-random-variables-such-that-the-correlation-coefficients-r/4450034#4450034)